# The best way to use mongodb, redis and rabbit mq through karatedsl?

Tags: mongodb, redis, rabbitmq, karate

Is there the best way for me to use mongodb, redis and rabbitmq through karatedsl ? or i have to write my own java code for them all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your own Java code, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java - and there is also a JDBC example as a reference: [`dogs.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/dogs/dogs.feature)

The reason we don't support all databases is that it will un-necessarily add complexity and a learning curve to Karate that will needlessly burden the 90% of users who don't need to call a database (for those who are too lazy to write glue code to do so ;).

Please note that the code to get data from the database is something you need to write only *one time*, and I suggest that you take the help of someone to do this. Once you have this in place, you can re-use it in all the tests you create.